# Segfault when deleting Nodes from a list (C)

Tags: c, list, segmentation-fault

Task is to have a program `write` & `read` objects from a `file`, then create a list out of them, then  delete `Node`-s with odd `int`-s. The deletion is done with a few nested functions. Problem is, there's a segfault somewhere. Of course, I ran this through a debugger, but we've neither been taught machine code/assembly language or how to use a debugger altogether.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct smallNode {
    int val;
    char str[10];
}smallNode;

typedef struct Node {
    smallNode smallNode;
    struct Node *next;
}Node;

Node *head = NULL;

Node *getLast(Node *head);
void queue(Node **head, Node *object);
void print(Node *head);
int countNodes(Node *head);
void check(Node *head);
Node *getNth(Node *head, int n);
void delNth(Node **head, int n);
void popHead(Node **head);
void delOdds(Node *head);


int main(void) {

    FILE *fp;
    if ((fp = fopen("suka.blyad", "wb")) == NULL) {
        return 69;
    }
    smallNode array[5];
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        array[j].val = j;
    }
    strcpy(array[0].str, "zero");
    strcpy(array[1].str, "one");
    strcpy(array[2].str, "two");
    strcpy(array[3].str, "three");
    strcpy(array[4].str, "four");
    int i;
    smallNode *object0 = (smallNode *)malloc(sizeof(smallNode));
    for (i = 0; i <5; i++) {
        *object0 = array[i];
        if (fwrite(object0, sizeof(smallNode), 1, fp) != 1) {
            puts("IO error.");
            exit(-3);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    if ((fp = fopen("suka.blyad", "rb")) == NULL) {
        return 4;
    }
    Node * object = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    while (1) {
        if (fread(object0, sizeof(smallNode), 1, fp) != 1) {
            break;
        }
        object->smallNode = *object0;
        queue(&head, object);
    }
    print(head);
    puts("After deleting odds: ");
    delOdds(head);
    print(head);
    return 0;
}

 void check(Node *head){ //function to check if the list exists 
    if(head == NULL){
        puts("NaL");
        exit(-1);
     }
 }

Node *getLast(Node *head) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    while (head->next) {
        head = head->next;
    }
    return head;
}

void queue(Node **head, Node *object) {
    Node *tmp = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    Node *last = getLast((*head));
    *tmp = *object;
    tmp->next = NULL;
    if (last != NULL) {
        last->next = tmp;
    }
    else {
        *(head) = tmp;;
    }
}
void print(Node *head) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        puts("NaL");
        exit(-4);
    }
    int c = 0;
    while (1) {
        printf("Node: %d.\n", ++c);
        puts("-----------------------------------------");
        printf("|Int: %6d    |    String: %7s  %3c\n", head->smallNode.val, head->smallNode.str, '|');
        puts("-----------------------------------------");
        if (head->next!=NULL) {
            head = head->next;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
}

int countNodes(Node *head){  //use this function to check out of bounds
    check(head);
    int count = 0;
    while(1){
        count++;
        if(head->next){
            head = head->next;
        }
        else{
            return count; 
        }
    }
}

Node *getNth(Node *head, int n){ 
    check(head);
    if(n > countNodes(head) 
       || n < 0){
        puts("Out of bounds.");
        exit(-5);
    }
    int i; 
    for(i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
        head = head->next;
    }
    return head;
}

void delNth(Node **head, int n){  //cant delete the first node 
    check((*head));
    Node *prev = getNth((*head), n-1);
    Node *elm = prev->next;
    prev->next = elm -> next;
    free(elm);
}

void popHead(Node **head){ //can only delete the first node, called only if n == 1
    check((*head));
    Node *elm = (*head);
    (*head) = (*head)->next;
    free(elm);
}

void delOdds(Node *head){ //function to go throught the list, check for odds and call the functions doing the deletion
    check(head);
    int n = 0;
    while(1){
        ++n;
        if(head->smallNode.val % 2){
            if(n == 1){
                popHead(&head);
            }
            else{
                delNth(&head, n);
            }
        }
        if(head->next){
            head = head->next;
        }
        else{
            print(head);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm including the whole code not just the problematic functions so the program can be ran.
I assume the way I create the list may be unorthodox, therefore I'll explain it briefly, so you don't bother figuring it out:
There's 2 types of objects used. `smallNode` doesn't have the `next` pointer, but it's the object written & read from file. It corresponds with `object0`.

`Node` is the object from which the list is made of, it's also the object that's being passed to the `queue` function, which creates the list.

Comment: "*I ran this through a debugger, but we've neither been taught machine code/assembly*" did you tell the compiler to add symbols and references to the sources file when compiling? Using GCC this can be done by specifying the option `-g`. The debugger then can provide you much more meaningful information. There then is no need to read machine code.

Comment: How the debugger is to be used should be explained in the debugger's documentation. Which compiler/debugger do you use?

Comment: @alk devc++ is the one I use

Comment: DevC++ is not a compiler, but an IDE (it probably uses the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler). Learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crash is seen because you are incrementing the local Head `head = head->next;` on each iteration and you are passing the same local Head to `delNth()` which uses `getNth()` function to get the Nth node. Since your `getNth()` function counts and returns the Nth node from the from the beginning the list, you end up pointing invalid address.

If you want to proceed with your own approach you need to do the following changes.

1. Maintain local pointer to iterate through the list.
2. change `delNth(Node **head, int n)` to `delNth(Node *head, int n)` to avoid the 
   altering the Head node.
3. while deleting pass the actual head.
4. After deleting decrement the `n` so your number of nodes and `n` are intact.

Following is the modified code.

```
void delOdds(Node *head){ 
        check(head);
        Node *localHead = head;
        int n = 0;
        while(1){
       printf("processing node=%d n=%d\n", localHead->smallNode.val, n);
            ++n;
            if(localHead->smallNode.val % 2){
                if(n == 1){
                    popHead(&head);
                }
                else{
                    delNth(head, n);
                    n--;
                }
            }
            if(localHead->next){
                localHead = localHead->next;
            }
            else{
                print(localHead);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I would suggest you to go with below approach.

```
void delOdds(Node **head){
        check(*head);
        Node *prev = NULL;
        Node *cur = *head;
        int n = 0;
        while(cur){
                if((cur)->smallNode.val % 2){
                        if (cur == *head)
                        {
                                *head = (*head)->next;
                                free(cur);
                                cur = *head;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                (prev)->next = (cur)->next;
                                free(cur);
                                cur = NULL;
                                (cur)=(prev)->next;
                        }
                }
                else{
                        prev = cur;
                        (cur)=(cur)->next;
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: This works, only thing it should be `print(head)`. As for the approach, I feel the way I do it is clunky, could you suggest a better one?